# Non admin users prompted for scopes after domain-wide install

Tags: google-oauth, google-apps-marketplace, google-workspace

I've created a GSuite Marketplace App that is meant to only be installed via domain admins to approve the required scopes for their entire domain. During the test installation process when I install the app as an administrator it prompts for the expected scopes and installs it for every user as expected. This is a Drive integration so when the user goes to Drive the app shows up in their list as expected. When I go to the "Manage API client access" section in GSuite admin, it correctly shows the app and the different scopes that were approved upon installation. So far so good.

When a user then goes to my app on my domain (either another non-admin user or my admin user that just installed the app), I expected that I'd be able to use the JS Client Library to authenticate them automatically without needing them to approve any scopes since the administrator should have domain-wide approved them. However, when I run the following code on the client, it's telling me the user isn't signed in.

```
gapi.load('client:auth2', () => {
    gapi.client.init({
        discoveryDocs: [''https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest'],
        clientId: //My applications client ID
        scope: //Same scopes that the admin user approved during install,
    })
    .then(() => {
        gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get(); //false
    })
```

Invoking the `gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();` method then pops up the scope approval with the same scopes that the admin approved domain-wide.

I might be missing the purpose of doing a domain-wide install, but I expected that the individual users wouldn't need to re-approve the scopes and that after the resolution of the `init` Promise above, I'd have access to the currently logged in user.

Am I wrong in my thinking there? The various documentation on this subject talk a lot about service accounts but I didn't think I'd need one for what I'm doing since I'm never doing server-server requests. All the API requests I'm making will be as the current user from the browser directly.

Is there something wrong where maybe the domain where I'm running the above code isn't configured correctly or something?

I've poked at almost all of the various configuration settings of both my Marketplace app and the project configuration but I still haven't found a way to make this as seamless as it seems like I can.